# Why does vector initialization constructs and copies?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am learning C++ and I have been looking at STL containers. I have many questions but I think this can go first. Consider this class and vector of it.

```
class A {
   int i;
   // A(const A&);
public:

   A(int i) : i(i) {cout << "consting " << i << endl;}
   A(const A& ot) : i(ot.i) {cout << "copying " << i << endl;}

};

int main () {
   vector<A> v1 = {A(1),A(2),A(3),A(4)};
   vector<A> v2(1,A(5));
   vector<A> v3;
   v3.push_back(A(6));
}
```

gives me the output

```
consting 1
consting 2
consting 3
consting 4
copying 1
copying 2
copying 3
copying 4
consting 5
copying 5
consting 6
copying 6
```

Clearly it is constructing and copying each `A`.

Is there some way of preventing this. What I mean is how can I avoid the extra copy and just construct `A` into the vector. Is this posssible. If not can someone explain why? Thank you.

EDIT: 
Just for completion's sake `push_back` does the same

Comment: The problem is that `std::initializer_list` "owns" it's content so every constructor using it has to copy the elements. It doesn't make sense but it's how `std::initializer_list` works. Bad luck.

Comment: @ipc What about the other construction cases? is that possible for the others?

Comment: @Aurora: Actually, it's far easier than you'd think.  Instead of adding `A(6)`, just add `6`.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately list initialization requires copies with `std::vector`. If you know that your container is fixed size, one alternative is to use an `std::array` instead:

```
std::array<A, 4> a1 = {{A(1),A(2),A(3),A(4)}};

stdout:
consting 1
consting 2
consting 3
consting 4
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't avoid having a copy when using the initializer list constructor like this. An alternative is to reserve the appropriate capacity at the beginning and then `emplace_back` each of the objects:

```
vector<A> v1;
v1.reserve(4);
v1.emplace_back(1);
v1.emplace_back(2);
v1.emplace_back(3);
v1.emplace_back(4);
```

[As you can see](http://ideone.com/gvfzFz), this results in only the following output:

```
consting 1
consting 2
consting 3
consting 4
```

Comment: @Aurora Right, but so is the initializer list constructor you're using.

Comment: @Aurora: Correct. The same applies to initialize lists that you appear to use in your code.

Comment: Ya actually I tried that hoping it would give different results. For the normal constructor and push_back I guess there is nothing to be done (if not C++11)?

Comment: @Aurora No, there is no way to do emplace construction before C++11 (other than `std::vector<A> v1(5);`, which would require a default constructor).